# How to prevent race condition in Lua?

Tags: multithreading, lua, race-condition

I am writing a Lua script that uses a library to access a hardware device with buttons. I register a callback function to handle the button presses. The code looks like:

```
globalvar = {}

function buttonCallback(buttonId)
    ...accessing globalvar
end

device.RegisterButtonCallback("buttonCallback")

while true do
end
```

This works.

Now I want to update the globalvar not only at a button presses but also at 1 minute intervals. Since I will need to access a network resource anyway I plan on using the socket.select call to get the 1 minute interval.

```
#require "socket"

globalvar = {}

function buttonCallback(buttonId)
    ...access globalvar
end

device.RegisterButtonCallback("buttonCallback")

while true do
    socket.select(nil, nil, 60)  -- wait 60 seconds
    ...access network
    ...access globalvar
end
```

Now I am concerned about the concurrent access of the globalvar. How can I prevent race conditions here? Most sources on multithreading in Lua advise to use continuations in cooperative scheduling but I don't see how that could be applied in my case.

Comment: It seems to me as if part of the puzzle is missing. Maybe you should provide more details of this library you're using.

Comment: Standard Lua is not thread safe. Consider splitting the code into separate VMs and handling threads in client code.

Comment: @iWerner: what details would be helpful? I can contact the author for more information, but I don't know what to ask.

Comment: @Bartek: I do not exactly see what you mean. What do you mean with VMs and client code?

Comment: Ah. I thought you were embedding it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took a deep dive into the Lua books and online documentation, and contacted the author of the device driver. As the answers already indicated, it takes much more than anticipated to handle the button callbacks safely.

My approach now is to write the device driver myself and use sockets as communication channel between the device and the Lua script.

My initial approach was to use continuations as this is advocated as the Lua "replacement" for multithreading but when I read the programming in Lua book, it turns out that in order to prevent busy waits, it uses the socket.select (!). This increased my feeling that a socket-based approach is good, especially since I also need sockets for internet access in my script.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the library you're using is creating another thread behind the scenes, and your only concern is about accessing `globalvar` from within the callback, you could avoid it by writing to a pipe in the callback, and reading from it in your `select` loop.  In other words, use a standard POSIX-style pipe to communicate the callback back to the main thread.  This is a fairly common technique when dealing with e.g. POSIX signals.

Comment: Is this something supported by the Lua standard libraries? When searching I found a luaposix library, do you mean using something like that? Your suggestion got me thinking: I could create a socket connection and have the button callback send a message to the main loop where I could use the select to pick up the button press. Feels a bit complicated but could do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Lua is not thread-safe within a particular `lua_State` instance. You *cannot* modify a global variable from one thread while another thread is doing something else with that Lua instance. You most certainly cannot be executing two separate scripts on the same instance.

Thread safety is something you have to do outside of Lua. You cannot have the C/C++ thread that detects the button press actually call Lua code directly. It must send that data to the main thread via some thread-safe mechanism, where *it* will call the Lua script for them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this mean that my script has to poll the device to see if a button was pressed? I see no way since my script has do things even when no button is ever pressed.